# scroll issue in chrome angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, angular5

I'm new in angular 5 and I'm developing a web app with it. The App works fine in Firefox but in Chrome, I get the following error:

> zone.js:1666 [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' 
>   to make the page more responsive ˋ

**`Package.json`:**

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "alertify.js": "^1.0.12",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "ng4-geoautocomplete": "^0.1.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^1.0.10",
    "ngx-filter-pipe": "^2.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.1.0",
    "ts-md5": "^1.2.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.108",
    "@types/socket.io-client": "^1.4.32",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}ˋ
```

Comment: Have you added any event listeners to a mousewheel event? Or are you manipulating the scroll event anywhere in your app? If so please show that code

Comment: @Und3rTow I have tried this solution but does not work for me: `document.addEventListener("wheel", function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
  }, {
     passive: true
  });`

Comment: May be this answer will do the trick
[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46542547/5173327).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error because I have included `smoothscroll.js` in my `angular-cli.json` which contains this code affecting mouse scroll event in chrome:

```
var ischrome = /chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
if (ischrome) {
  ssc_addEvent("mousedown", ssc_mousedown);
  ssc_addEvent("mousewheel", ssc_wheel);
  ssc_addEvent("load", ssc_init)
}
```

after removing it, my app works perfectly fine.